# Does the analysis of mouse/keyboard motions of a user have a special name?

Tags: tracking, analysis, motion

I'm searching for information about the analysis of a users motion/typing with the mouse or keyboard on websites. Yet I'm not able to find that much when searching about it. Does there exist a special name for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think '*user interaction tracking*' or '*web analytics*' are the terms you should be looking for.